# Symfony: Action "css/images" does not exist

Tags: symfony1

I notice the above waring/error in my php error log file generated for my symfony website.

I can't for the life of me, what is causing it. I am sure I have gone through every css file, as well as image tag (explicity hand crafted or generated using image_tag() etc), and I cannot find where I am using an image path name that would be resolved as css/image under the web folder.

I have also looked at my templates and layout.php file - there are no references to images in css/images.

I need to find out:

- Has anyone come accross this before?
- Am I missing checking/looking at something obvious?
- What is the fix?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Its on my local dev machine

Answer (score 2):

The error appears to be the generic action not found error. It occurs because the apache rewrite rules explicitly redirect all request to the front controller unless there is a file extension in the url and the file exists on the file system.

The error would imply there is a request to css/images in one of you html templates, or more likely, and url() reference to "images/" in you css somehwere.

I've noticed this happen a lot with jquery ui when you move the images directory out of the css folder.

You might be able to see the offending request in Firebug or Webkit Inspector.

Comment: Indeed - he is most probably using `url(images/...)` somewhere in his css instead of `url(/images/...)`